# Wordpress Comments without plug-ins

Tags: wordpress, conditional-comments

I am creating a blog for my site using Word Press. The only part of the site managed by word press will be the blog. So far I have created a basic theme which displays my blog posts however I don't have anything offering users the option to comment on my blog posts.

This is something I want to have implemented. I am against the idea of installing plug-ins but I am new to the Word Press platform so was wondering if someone could offer any suggestions in regards to how I would go about performing this within Word Press (preferably without a plug-in)

Thanks

Comment: you don't want to use WordPress's built-in commenting system?

Comment: I am using the built in comment system. I have just created my own custom theme. However even though in the 'Discussions' section under the admin dashboard I have checked all the option to allow for commenting. Yet when I log out as admin and view my blog there is no option to comment on the posts I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you do want to use WordPress's built-in commenting system, you can enable that in the `settings` under `discussion` -- just need to click the box next to "Allow people to post comments on new articles" (along with whatever other settings you wish)

from SO comment thread... support for WP comments discussed in part 2 of tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch-part-2/

Comment: Like I mentioned above. I have that checked already yet there is still no option to comment on my posts. I have logged out at as admin to test and nowhere can I post a comment etc. on the post that already exists. Should there be a text box allowing users to comment on this or a link which directs them to somewhere they can post?

Comment: ok, I understand now. if you look at the default themes that are part of WordPress, you'll see `comments.php` and references to comments in other files.

Comment: So I'm just missing the comments.php file? Or is there any more that I will need to add

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing everything in the theme. did you start from an existing theme? or did you create this from scratch?

Comment: I used some most code from this but my own stylesheet etc. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/

Comment: Working from a local server will try and get a copy of the blog online

Comment: part 2 of that tutorial covers the comment system, maybe there is something that was missed? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch-part-2/

Comment: I didn't realise the second part of the tutorial was available. Great, ill check that out and let you know how I get on :)